# how to count specific row where variable can be more then one

Tags: c#, mysql

how i can write the query ex;-

```
select count(id) where animal = rat , elephant ,cat, mouse
```

how i can do this in mysql.
ex means count the row where animal = rat ,elephant, cat ,mouse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return a single `COUNT` for all matching animals:

```
SELECT  COUNT(id)
WHERE   animal IN ('rat', 'elephant' , 'cat', 'mouse')
```

This will count animal-wise:

```
SELECT  animal, COUNT(id)
WHERE   animal IN ('rat', 'elephant' , 'cat', 'mouse')
GROUP BY
        animal
```

i. e. will return how many rats, elephants etc. are there in the table.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost correct. You write

```
WHERE var IN (value1, value2, ..., valueN)
```

This is equivalent with

```
WHERE var = value1 OR var = value2 OR var = .... OR var = valueN
```